# How to go over angular collection

Tags: angular, components

I have the following structure in Component:

```
const Data = {
"java : [{text: "question", answer: "yes"},
    {text: "some question", answer: "yes"}],
"python":[{text: "some question", answer: "yes"},
        {text: "some question", answer: "no"}],
}
}
```

And now I want to go over this collection and output questions with answers in the list. I am doing that like this:

```
 <p *ngFor="let line of currentComponent" class="center">
    {{line.text}}
    {{line.answer}}
 </p>
```

But this code doesn't show anything. If I try to display currentComponent it displays

> [object Object],[object Object]

currentComponent is deffined:

```
export class ThisComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title:string;

  currentComponent:ThisComponent;

  line:string;    

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentComponent = this.thisServise.getCourse(this.title);
  }

}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Who is currentComponent

Comment: @alehn96 added definition to the my question

Comment: I don't understand why the object is the type CourseComponent, it is wrong, change to any[] or other model

Comment: Add a breakpoint into the `ngOnInit` event. What value does the `title` variable have?

Comment: @DzouSi, what is this `CourseComponent`?

Comment: Can you modify the http://plnkr.co/edit/cVIT0ddyZ19SZ7AQxU8U?p=preview Plunker sample to illustrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do. This won't work. It sounds like you want a separate class/interface to define your data. It should simplify your solution.

```
// in something like 'data.model.ts'
export interface Data {
  name: string; //eg: 'java'
  text: string; //eg: 'question?'
  answer: string; //eg: 'yes'
}
```

And then you would want your service to return Data objects.

```
// in your service class
data: Data[] = [
  {name: 'java', text: 'foo', answer: 'no'},
  {name: 'python', text: 'bar', answer: 'yes'}
];

// ...
// you could use filtering here since data is an array of objects
getDataForLanguage(language: string) { 
  return this.data.filter(course -> {
    return course.name == language;
  }) 
}
```

It would be something like that. I didn't go and compile the code to check, but that would be the approach I took rather than trying to manipulate a complex Object like what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `currentComponent: CourseComponent;` to
`currentComponent: Array<{ text: string, answer: string }>;`